# C++ subscript operator format

Tags: c++, arrays, operators

Why is the following form of addressing an element of an array with index 1 correct?

```
int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
// this statement:
std::cout << 1[a];
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: The short answer is C. The slightly longer answer is "Arrays were defined in terms of pointer arithmetic in C, and so the expression `a[b]` is defined as `*(a + b)`.". I'm sure someone will come up with a better answer than that though, or show how I'm subtly wrong. But that's the basic gist of the reason. That does not work for overloaded versions of `operator []` though, only for bare pointer types and plain old integers.

Comment: There are a lot of posts at SO that contain the phrase "The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))". See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+The+expression+E1%5BE2%5D+is+identical.

Comment: @RSahu - I am terrible at hunting for duplicates. :-(

Comment: @Omnifarious, it's not always easy. BTW, I posted that comment for the benefit of the OP.